# Password less Local user account in windows 10 enterprise

Tags: windows-10, passwords

For the internal application authentication purposes, would like to have a `password less local user account in one of our windows 10 enterprise system`. Tried to create a local account but getting below error.

[image]

In windows-10 it is not possible to have an account without password (Or)PIN?

Comment: Based on the error message I would assume that your company deploys a group policy that defines a minimum password security requirement (e.g. minimum password length) which implicitly refuses to create accounts without a password.

Comment: @Robert, Will remove the system from domain and try.

Comment: You'll need to exempt the account from various password restriction. Type `secpol.msc` (as an admin). Remote logons without password are disabled by default etc.